# Refresh page when delete row from database

Tags: java, database

I  have 'treinkoverzicht.java' which makes an table what get some information from my SQL database.

You can see the select query in AdminScherm.java (see: AdminScherm.java below).

The problem is: If i'm click on the delete button(called: verwijder), it deletes the record out of my database (Delete query), that is ok of course. But it doesn't update my screen directly, so it looks like the deleted row is still in the table and database.
Like a refresh of my page direct when you push the (verwijder) delete button.

(treinkoverzicht.java) , below: /

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 if ("Bekijk foto".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
        BekijkFoto b = new BekijkFoto(koeriers.get(Integer.parseInt(btn.getName())));
        b.setVisible(true);z

   } else if ("Verwijder".equals(e.getActionCommand())) { 
        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
        int keuze1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
            this, 
            "Weet u zeker dat u deze treinkoerier wilt verwijderen?",
            "Verwijderen",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (keuze1 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            try {
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                String verwijderenkoerier = "DELETE FROM coerier WHERE CoerierID=" + koeriers.get(Integer.parseInt(btn.getName())).getId();
                stmt.executeUpdate(verwijderenkoerier);
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException a) {
                System.out.println("Statement kan niet worden uitgevoerd.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as the actionPerformed() goes in AdminScherm.java should reload his queries.

(AdminScherm.java) , below: /

```
treinO = new TreinKOverzicht(this);

String sqlkoerier = "SELECT * FROM coerier";
try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlkoerier);

    while (rs.next()) {
    int id = rs.getInt("CoerierID");//aangepast
    String naam = rs.getString("FirstName");
    String achternaam = rs.getString("LastName");
    String email = rs.getString("Email");
    int telefoonnummer = rs.getInt("Telephone");
    int kmreward = rs.getInt("KmReward");

    TreinKoerier t = new TreinKoerier(id, naam, achternaam, email, telefoonnummer, kmreward);//aangepast
    treinO.voegTreinKToe(t);
    }
} catch (SQLException sd) {
    System.out.println("Statement kan niet worden uitgevoerd.");
}
treinO.printTabel();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the "treinkoerier" manually from the table after the database query.

BTW: Keep your code the same as your database, I prefer both in english!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! We gonna try it. Next time we keep it English ;)

Comment: Okay, succes ermee! :P 
Als je nog vragen hebt hoor ik het graag.
P.S. Zou je het antwoord als 'Answer' willen vinken?